# replace the following string

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var str = "I'm a very^ montréal Str!ng.";
```

How do I replace it with `I-m-a-very-montreal-Strng`

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make sure you tag your question with proper labels (programming language, relevant technologies etc). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: If you only want to replace one string by another just do it explicitly. If you want to implement some logic please explain that logic. Give more example pairs of input and expected output. Try to define your abstract goal by describing it in prose. I.e. try to explain why `var str = "I-m-a-very-montreal-Strng";` is not an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need `split()` and `join()` functions. For the string you have given, the code should be:

```
str = str.split(' ').join('-');
str = str.split('é').join('e');
str = str.split('!').join('i');
str = str.split('^').join('');
str = str.split("'").join('-');
```